# SQL Server TDE - encryption_state 2 stuck at 100% complete

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2019, transparent-data-encryption

I have enabled TDE on two databases. 
One is around 700 GB and that completed over the night and has encryption_state=3 
The other one is almost 2 TB. That one has encryption_state=2 and percent_complete 100

Should i just be patient and wait, or can there be a problem since it is stuck at 100% complete? 
I don't know when it reached 100% but it's about 17 hours since i enabled encryption on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sorted itself out.

Maybe it just needed time or maybe it was a log backup that fixed it as those run at set intervals.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cycle the transaction log before it is done.

Do a log backup if you are in full recovery.

If you are in simple it should happen automatically, but you can stress it using the CHECKPOINT command.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to do a checkdb.

```
DBCC CHECKDB ('2TB_database_name')
```

Maybe you have a corrupted page that can't be encrypted.
Handle it or them and then rerun the alter database set encryption on.